# EF Core: updating an entity without querying it first

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm looking for a way to update a property of an entity by knowing its primary key, without first querying it.

The solution I've come up with is this one:

```cs
var order = new OrderEntity()
{
    Id = 5
};

db.Orders.Attach(order).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

order.Name = "smth";

db.SaveChanges();
```

Which seems to work fine, as the generated SQL is exactly what I expect:

```sql
UPDATE "Orders" SET "Name" = @p0
WHERE "Id" = @p1;
```

**Question**: is this the correct way of doing it?

I can't find any confirmation about this in the official documentation, or anywhere else on the web actually. Similar questions are about Entity Framework (non-Core) and they seem to use different strategies, like setting `EntityState.Modified` instead of `Unchanged`. I tried that as well but it has the effect of updating all the properties, which is not what I want to achieve. So I'm wondering if there's something I'm missing about the solution above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for [DbContext.Attach Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.attach?view=efcore-3.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbContext_Attach_System_Object_) says:

> Begins tracking the given entity and entries reachable from the given entity using the **Unchanged** state by default, but see below for cases when a different state will be used.
>   [...]
>   For entity types with generated keys if an entity has its primary key value set then it will be tracked in the **Unchanged** state. If the primary key value is not set then it will be tracked in the **Added** state.
>   [...]
>   For entity types without generated keys, the state set is always **Unchanged**.
>   [...]

So setting the state to `Unchanged` is not even  necessary.

But be careful. If you set e.g. `order.Amount = 0m;` to clear the amount, this will not work, as no change will be detected. Write

```
var order = new OrderEntity()
{
    Id = 5,
    Amount = 1.00m; // Dummy value unequal 0.00m
};
db.Orders.Attach(order);

// Make the change    
order.Amount = 0.00m; // Now, this change will be detected.

db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Ah, right! I didn't think about that. I guess a workaround would be to force the value to be considered as modified: `db.Entry(order).Property(x => x.Amount).IsModified = true;`. It's a bit verbose though.

Comment: I just noticed that the link you provided is about EF6 and not EF Core, so that explains why I couldn't find the behaviour mentioned. I guess it's the same in this case though

Comment: Sorry. I changed the reference. The text for EF Core is different but basically it tells the same story. Setting the property state to `IsModified` is certainly a very robust method.

Comment: Thanks. It's not the official docs though. I now see that the default state is well explained in the [API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.attach?view=efcore-3.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbContext_Attach_System_Object_) but not in the page about detached entities